# Font tails in headlines

Tags: css

Hello I have problem which you can see here: http://adrianwajs.pl/monika/. "coming soon" sign when you hover over h2,which wraps it you can see that, in firebug you can see that letter g doesn't fit the height of h2 element. I have seen it many times but I can't find solution for this, maybe someone has?

Comment: please include your html and css in your question.

Comment: maybe set some more padding on your h2. also it says comming soon instead of coming soon :p

Comment: looks fine to me in IE, Chrome and Firefox - which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: If you play around with the font, you can see the declaimer div adjusts it's margin-top, so it's clearly the font you choose. You want that "g" to overlap the div below ? And if you want you can either set it manually by changing the padding or height.

Comment: If the descender descends below the element, and it's a problem, you simply need a larger `line-height`.

Comment: 1. Css can be found in link that I presented
2. Padding isn't good solution because there can be without any y,g,p chars and then space will be too big.
3. I checked in FF 21 on linux but on FF 21 on windows 7 it was bad too. It may look ok because .disclaimer has proper margin.
4. You mean that it's because of font and it cannot be changed? 
5. line-height isn't the solution check it in firebug.

Comment: What do you mean by “check it in firebug”? What is the problem as visible to users?

Comment: From visibilyty currently there are no problems, but try to remove margin-top from .desclaimer and you will see the problem.

Comment: @adi86 Please don't say "you will see the problem". As all the answers and comments show, we clearly don't see the problem. Can you provide a screen shot of what you're seeing, preferably with a little arrow pointing to the position where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your h2 says 'Comming Soon' Instead of 'Coming Soon'

I don't see a problem in Chrome, IE, Firefox.

There are two things you can do:

- More padding on your h2 tag. for example `h2 { padding: 30px; }`
- A line-height of for example like `line-height: 1.5;`

Comment: line-height increases height of h2 element which is not desiered.

padding isn't good solution too because when I have text without any g,y,p etc. chars spacing would be too big.

Comment: If we are speaking about what you see I know it works ok because .disclaimer has proper margin-top, but when you delete it you can see that .disclaimer is overlapping g in coming soon text.

Comment: When I delete the disclaimer in firebug it's still working properly.

Comment: I mean not deleteing whole div disclaimer but to remove margin-top property from it :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, a glyph may well extend below the bottom edge of a line box, even when text is set solid (line height equals font size). This is up to the font designer. If this causes a problem, use a larger line height or a different font.

On your page, the descender does not actually extend that far, as you can see by drawing an outline for the heading, for example. However it almost extends to the bottom of the font and far below the baseline; this is not uncommon in fonts that imitate handwriting.

**Update:** The features of the Pacifico font used on the page cause line boxes containing text in that font to have a largish height, larger than `line-height`. On the page, in Firefox, the `span` containing “Comming soon” is 128 pixels high for such reasons and thus extends past its container, the `h2` element.

Line box heights are calculated by browsers on the basis of height requirements, including font properties, and there is no direct way to control this. You just need to live with it and provide sufficient spacing with margins or padding.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation, I thought that it can be somehow fixed. This bug can be quite tricky because when you have more generic text and there can be no chars like: y, g, p etc. in it the the bottom padding will cause unnecessary spacing below text.